# Detect Touch&Type keyboard 

Tags: blackberry

Is there is any API to detect the keyboard in touch and type series of blackberry, i.e. Blackberry bold 9930.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 DeviceCapability.isPhysicalKeyboardAvailable();
```

It returns `true` if there is an physical keyboard.

Otherwise returns `false`.